# How to disable a built-in command in vim

Tags: vim, command, built-in, remap

In vim, when I hit `:wq` it is almost always an accident that occurred when attempting to input `:w`.  I would like to disable `:wq`.

The closest I found is `cmap`, but it has some odd behavior.  If I do something like

```
:cmap wq w
```

I can no longer even input `:wq`; it just remaps the keystroke sequence `wq` to `w` in command mode.  Now I cannot, for example, input a search/replace command on a string containing `wq`.

I would just like to alias the exact command `:wq` to `:w` or a no-op.  Is there a way to do this?

EDIT: clarified why `:cmap` is not an option for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the best option is to just get used to `:cmap` behavior.  In the rare event I want to input the keyboard seqeunce `wq` I can just hit `wq`, wait a second, then hit `q` again.  I did find [this possible solution](http://marc.info/?l=vim&m=104916638819705&w=2) but it is too complex for my tastes.

Answer (score 5):

A better solution can be:

```
:cabbrev wq w
```

But I'm not sure why `cmap` doesn't work as excepted. 
Actually I had mapped one my function keys to save files:

```
:map <F2> :w<CR>
:nmap <F2> <ESC>:w<CR>i
```

***UPDATE***: typo corrected in the first command.

***UPDATE2***: possible workaround:

```
:cabbrev wq<CR> w
```

HTH

Comment: Can you please explain :cabbrew ?

Comment: I think it should be `:cabbrev`.  `:cabbrev wq w` will change wq to w after you press space or enter, so it will make `:wq` do `:w`.  See `:help :cabbrev` and `:help :ab` for more information.

Comment: Sorry, I think I was not clear enough in my question.

If you do :cmap and it also seems :cabbrew, it means the "wq" keystroke sequence in command mode is mapped to something other than "wq". So then you cannot, for example, do a search/replace on a string containing "wq".  All I would like to do is make it so if I input the exact command :wq, it is aliased to "w" or no-op.

Comment: Thanks AI, typo corrected.
I'm diving into the problem. as it's not the correct solution.

Comment: Just stopping by to say thanks - I am trying to weene myself off tabs, so doing `cabbrev tabnew help!<CR>` made vim give an error message every time I try to make a tab.

Answer (score 0):

I added a one-line patch and ran dpkg-rebuildpackage for renaming `:wa` to `:wwa`:

```
--- neovim/src/nvim/ex_cmds.lua
+++ neovim/src/nvim/ex_cmds.lua
@@ -3057,7 +3057,7 @@
     func='ex_wnext',
   },
   {
-    command='wall',
+    command='wwall',
     flags=bit.bor(BANG, TRLBAR, CMDWIN),
     addr_type=ADDR_LINES,
     func='do_wqall',
```

You will need to create this patch in `debian/patches/` and add it to `debian/patches/series`.