# How to redefine a command in Vim?

Tags: vim, command, definition

In vim, in my .vimrc, how can I redefine a command (i.e. :e) as something else?
I want to redefine `:e *` as `:tabe *`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured out a way to do it. See [How to disable a built-in command in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787127/how-to-disable-a-built-in-command-in-vim/1787963#1787963) . From that, we can see that we can use cabbrev to change what a command does. For my needs, `cabbrev e tabe` is perfect.

But we can generalize this solution to make commands starting with lower case characters accessible to users for user-defined ones: use cabbrev to (re)define a built-in command as a user-defined one. As such, we are able to redefine built-in commands as well as user-defined ones.

Here's an example, which is equivalent to my aforementioned solution to my problem:

```
:command -nargs=+ E :tabe "<args>"
:cabbrev e E
```

That's all.

Comment: This breaks if you want to type: `echo e f`, which would become `echo E f` instead. My answer attempts to overcome this.

Answer (score 12):

**`cnoreabbrev` workaround**

The best workaround without a plugin that I have seen so far is:

```
cnoreabbrev <expr> e getcmdtype() == ":" && getcmdline() == 'e' ? 'tabe' : 'e'
```

---

If you use a simple:

```
cnoreabbrev e E
```

as suggested by @Yktula would break your command if you want to do:

```
echo e f
```

which would become:

```
echo E f
```

instead.

---

As explained by @pydave in the comments, the [cmdalias plugin](https://github.com/vim-scripts/cmdalias.vim) adds a simpler interface to doing the safe alias simply as:

```
:Alias e tabe
```

At the time of writing the plugin also uses the `getcmdtype() == ":"` technique to implement its functionality.

Comment: You can use [cmdalias](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=746) to simplify that to `:Alias e tabe` and it will do the getcmdline magic for you.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you can't. User defined commands must have an uppercase first letter.

```
  :help :command
```

for more information